Increase Image Button Size on Yikes Easy Form
I have an embedded Yikes Easy Form for Mailchimp on my Wordpress page (https://indigomarketingagency.com/supercharge-your-financial-advisory-business-with-our-seo-checklist/) and have opted for an image in place of a standard button.  The image is being displayed, but it is super small.  I've added the following custom css, but the image is still not resizing:


.yikes-easy-mc-form .yikes-easy-mc-submit-button-image
{
  width: 500px!important;
 }



What changes to the css do I need to make in order for the button image to be resized?

Please also put the HTML code

Please see Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.

First of all the one thing that is blocking the image from being resized is max-width property and this property is something that is defined in the CSS of Yikes Form Button.
.yikes-easy-mc-form .yikes-easy-mc-submit-button-image {
    padding: 0;
    width: 99%;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 243px;
}

So, according to me in order for you to resize the button image you may also need to override the max-width: 243px; in your custom CSS you may add another !important if required for this property.
.yikes-easy-mc-form .yikes-easy-mc-submit-button-image
{
    width: 500px!important;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

